# xCode install older iOS SDK

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk

I've recently updated xCode to the newest version. (which includes iOS SDK 6.1) The problem is, that i want to make my apps available for all iOS versions, starting at version 5.0. Is this even possible?

Best regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to Xcode->Preferences->Downloads->install Simulators to test all iOS versions.

For setting your application minimum iOS version, goto Targets->Summary->Deployment Target->Set to 5.0

Hope this helps you..

Comment: Hi thank's for your answer! I already set the deployment target to iOS5.0, but is this enought? .. Isn't there a problem with the base SDK set on 6.1, when submitting to the appstore?

Comment: Base SDK to Latest iOS 6.1 have no relation to minimum iOS version

Comment: Ok, so if i set the deployment target to 5.0 everyone who has ios 5.0 or above can install the app?.. Just one last question.. What happens if i use stuff that is only available in ios6 (i.e. the new maps or share functionality)

Comment: For map, iOS 5.1 people will see Google Maps where as for iOS 6.0 people will see Apple Map, you don't need to code anything for that. For Sharing of Facebook, you need to check what is iOS version handle that similarly.

Comment: On my installation of Xcode, the only other simulator I see is 6.1, but I'm looking for 4.2. And counsel on how to find 4.2?